Panic running benchmarking with `pallet_identity` due to sr25519 signature
I have included pallet_identity in my runtime, but when running benchmarks, I encountered a panic with the following message:
Sr25519 not supported for EthereumSignature

It makes sense because the signature type in the runtime panics when trying to convert from a type other than ecdsa. However, the pallet benchmarking code uses MultiSignature::Sr25519, which causes the panic.
Is there any way I can solve this issue?
Additionally, I encountered another error when running benchmarks, although it did not cause a panic:
2024-08-29 10:52:05 [  0 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_identity::add_registrar    
2024-08-29 10:52:05 [  4 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_identity::set_identity    
2024-08-29 10:52:05 Error executing and verifying runtime benchmark: JudgementPaymentFailed    
2024-08-29 10:52:05 [  8 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_identity::set_subs_new    
2024-08-29 10:52:07 [ 13 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_identity::set_subs_old    
2024-08-29 10:52:08 [ 17 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_identity::clear_identity    
2024-08-29 10:52:08 Error executing and verifying runtime benchmark: JudgementPaymentFailed    
2024-08-29 10:52:08 [ 21 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_identity::request_judgement    
2024-08-29 10:52:09 [ 26 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_identity::cancel_request    
2024-08-29 10:52:10 [ 26 % ] Running  benchmark: pallet_identity::cancel_request(1 args) 7/50 1/1    
2024-08-29 10:52:11 [ 30 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_identity::set_fee    
2024-08-29 10:52:11 [ 34 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_identity::set_account_id    
2024-08-29 10:52:12 [ 39 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_identity::set_fields    
2024-08-29 10:52:13 [ 43 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_identity::provide_judgement    
2024-08-29 10:52:14 [ 47 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_identity::kill_identity    
2024-08-29 10:52:14 Error executing and verifying runtime benchmark: JudgementPaymentFailed    

Could this be related to the previous issue?
